# Creating a JAR file out of some class files

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, manifest

I am learning Java at the moment, and I am having a problem creating a JAR file out of some of my class files.

I searched the internet, and I found this command line:

```
jar cfmv Client.jar mainClass.txt Client.class Display.class Game1.class input.class
```

It compiles without any errors, but when opening the file using CMD, it says there isn't a main class or it couldn't be found:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main
```

I then found that I should add my main class to the manifest.mf. There's just one problem. I don't know my classpath. Can anyone help me to find this?
If it helps, this is what's on the left in Eclipse:

```
> Online game
  > src
    > (default package)
      > Client.java
      > Server.java
  > JRE System Library
```

Thanks in advance,

~Rik

Comment: Do your classes depend on any external library (i.e. any other jar file)? If not, you don't need to specify any classpath in the manifest. Also, I would advise to never put any class in the default package, and to respect the naming conventions. The `input` class should be named `Input`.

Comment: Well, my classes don't depend on any external library or something, but what would you advise to fix my error? By the way, my input class is just named input, it shouldn't be named Input as far as I know. And can I just easily rename my package?

Comment: Yes, it should be named Input because, by convention, class names always start with an uppercase letter. And not respecting conventions makes your code hard to read by everyone, including you. You found out that you had to specify your main class in the manifest. So do it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: Ah thanks JB Nizet, was really hard to find such a link! Fixed this stupid error in like one minute with that link :). Thanks really much!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Usually, googling for "Java tutorial <topic>" returns the appropriate tutorial page as the first link.

Comment: this helped me while creating jar 
http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can just right-click on your project and choose "Export" then "Runnable jar file". Then you need to select your Class with the `public static void main(String[] args)` entry point and Finish. Eclipse will create the jar for you.

Comment: It seemed like a really nice way to export my JAR, but still:     C:\Users\Meneer\workspace\Online game\src\Client\JAR file>java -jar Test.jar
no main manifest attribute, in Test.jar